# Oracle: missing right parenthesis

Tags: oracle, sql-like

I have a query:

```
SELECT (column LIKE '%string%') AS bool FROM table
```

It returns:

> "missing right parenthesis"

Why?

Comment: What is this query trying to do?

Comment: Oracle does not support boolean data types, so you will have to use string literals like 'TRUE', 'FALSE' or numerics like 1, 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of the `LIKE` operator, we can't use the `DECODE` function. I guess the following, as ugly as it is, matches what you're looking for:

```
SELECT
    login,
    CASE 
        WHEN login LIKE 'admin' THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END
FROM users;
```

or, with boolean like values:

```
SELECT
    login,
    CASE 
        WHEN login LIKE 'admin' THEN 'TRUE'
        ELSE 'FALSE'
    END
FROM users;
```

If you are using the `LIKE` operator, you would like to use some `%` wildcards in the 'admin' string, otherwise a simple equality is enough.

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/86034/7)

[Documentation](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/case.php)

Comment: It returns now: FROM keyword not found where expected

Comment: can we see the final query please?

Comment: LIKE without wildcards is the same as equals.

Comment: yes it is, but I assumed that he knew the use of LIKE was motivated by further strings manipulation hence I didn't change it.

Comment: finaly used your version :)

Answer (score 1):

You should use :

```
SELECT DECODE(login,'admin','TRUE','FALSE') as bool FROM users;
```

Comment: Good solution but whildcard isn't allowed.

Answer (score 1):

Officially there is no boolean datatype in SQL and there isn't one in Oracle.

The standard way of doing this would be with a WHERE clause:

```
select whatever 
from your_table
where column LIKE '%string%';
```

If you really want a column instead you need to combine a string probe with either DECODE() or CASE().  Like this...

```
select decode(instr(column, 'string'), 0, 'FALSE', 'TRUE') as bool
from your_table
```

... or this ...

```
select case when column like '%string%' then 'TRUE' else 'FALSE' end as bool
from your_table
```

... or some other permutation.

Answer (score 0):

It returns 1 - string found, otherwise 0:

```
SELECT LEAST(1,INSTR(login,'admin')) AS bool FROM users
```